# How to query last data, but except first query on last data

Tags: php, mysql

I have such datas in the table 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

**Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `post_id` DESC LIMIT 4
```

**Result:**

```
10,9,8,7
```

But i want like result this.

```
9,8,7
```

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `post_id` DESC LIMIT 1,4
```

More about limit and offset you can find here 
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp